# Finding Probability of $Pr(X=5| X>2)$

Tags: probability

Hi I got stuck on this question and I am not sure how to do it.

The question is:

$Pr(X=5|X>2)$

The table given is

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
x & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\ \hline
Pr(X=x) & \frac16 & \frac16 & \frac16 & \frac13 & \frac16
   \\ \hline
    \end{array}

Then answer given is $\frac25$.

Comment: It will help see it if you use a common denominator; write $\Pr(X=5)$ as $\tfrac 26$.

Answer (score 4):

By the definition of conditional probability,
\begin{align*}
\Pr(X=5\mid X>2) &= \frac{\Pr(X=5,X>2)}{\Pr(X>2)} = \frac{\Pr(X=5)}{\Pr(X>2)} = \frac{1/3}{1/6+1/6+1/3+1/6} \\
&= \frac2{1+1+2+1} = \frac25.
\end{align*}